# Can we have the reasons why 'Does anyone know free DIY ultralight plans?' is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

The question [Does anyone know free DIY ultralight plans?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/72968/does-anyone-know-free-diy-ultralight-plans) has been closed as off-topic, but there are no reasons given for this.  I don't necessarily want to challenge the decision, but it would be useful to have the reasons, if only so that I and others don't repeat the mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the problem with broad close reasons, they're not very specific. You have to follow a couple of links to the [on-topic help](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and then you will see one of the *off*-topic guidelines states:

> **Resource location**
>   Where to buy a specific part, "Which headset is the best?", Where can I get a feed of flight-related data? etc.

Related:

- [Are shopping-like questions allowed here?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/are-shopping-like-questions-allowed-here/2993#2993)
- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here/286#286)
- [Should we allow questions asking for resources?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/should-we-allow-questions-asking-for-resources/16#16)